# spring jdbctemplate get byte array

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am storing xml as byte array in the clob column in the oracle database.
Now trying to use jdbctemplate to get the resultset as byte array in spring batch.It's throwing below Exception

> **org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException**: StatementCallback; SQL [select DEFAULT_REPORT_PARAM_XML from
>   cfg_report_list  where report_name='Payments STP Report'"];
>   Unsupported feature; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Unsupported feature

PFB code sample which I am using

```
byte[] configxml = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                "select DEFAULT_REPORT_PARAM_XML from cfg_report_list  where report_name='Payments STP Report'", 
                byte[].class);
```

Please note that I am using spring-batch 3.0.1 RELEASE.

Kindly let me know solution to this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No need to call `getBlob()`; you should be able to simplify like it like so:

```
byte[] configxml = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
    "select DEFAULT_REPORT_PARAM_XML from cfg_report_list  where report_name='Payments STP Report'",
    (rs, rowNum) -> rs.getBytes(1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use a `RowMapper` and then use `ResultSet.getBlob`

```
public class YourXmlRowMapper implements RowMapper<byte[]> {

    public byte[] mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
         Blob column = rs.getBlob("DEFAULT_REPORT_PARAM_XML");
         return column.getBytes(1, column.length());
    }
}



byte[] configxml = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            "select DEFAULT_REPORT_PARAM_XML from cfg_report_list  where  report_name='Payments STP Report'", 
           new YourXmlRowMapper());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use byte[] instead of Byte[].